# nbconvert to markdown: avoid indents in code cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, nbconvert

I have a working notebook `notebook.ipynb` which I want to convert to a Markdown file (`output.md`) using `nbconvert`. I'm looking for a way to **avoid code outputs in the original notebook to be indented** in the `output.md` output.

Input `notebook.ipynb`

[image]

Executed command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to markdown --output output.md notebook.ipynb
```

Output:

```
# This is a simple test


'''python
print("<mark>Test</mark>")
'''

    <mark>Test</mark>
```

Expected output (no indentation):

```
# This is a simple test


'''python
print("<mark>Test</mark>")
'''

<mark>Test</mark>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround (not really a solution): using `display(HTML())` instead of `print()`.

Use:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<mark>Test</mark>"))
```

instead of:

```
print("<mark>Test</mark>")
```